# How can I set default value to exceptions in automapper while mapping from string to int type property?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, automapper

I am trying to map one object to another but I am getting a problem while mapping an empty string to type int or a non integer string to `int`, so what I want that if I such exceptions occur it must assign some default value to it, let say -1.

for example we have a class `A` and Class `B`

```
 Class A
 {
     public string a{get;set;}
 }
 Class B
 {
     public int a{get;set;}
 }
```

Now if we map from class `A` to `B` using default rule it will through exception if string is empty or non integer.

Please help me fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StackOverFlowAnswers
{
    public class LineItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }


    public class AutoMappingTests
    {
        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void TestFixtureSetUp()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Model, LineItem>()
                  .ForMember(x => x.Amount, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<StringToInteger>());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestBadStringToDefaultInteger()
        {
            // Arrange
            var model = new Model() {Id = 1, ProductId = "awesome-product-133-XP", Amount = "EVIL STRING, MWUAHAHAHAH"};

            // Act
            LineItem mapping1 = Mapper.Map<LineItem>(model);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(model.Id, mapping1.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(model.ProductId, mapping1.ProductId);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, mapping1.Amount);


            // Arrange
            model.Amount = null; // now we test null, which we said in options to map from null to -1

            // Act
            LineItem mapping2 = Mapper.Map<LineItem>(model);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(-1, mapping2.Amount);

        }

    }

    public class StringToInteger : ValueResolver<Model, int>
    {
        protected override int ResolveCore(Model source)
        {
            if (source.Amount == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            int value;

            if (int.TryParse(source.Amount, out value))
            {
                return value; // Wahayy!!
            }

            return 0; // return 0 if it could not parse!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the above code works too while i am sharing one code which i made myself as it works too

```
public class StringToIntTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, int>
{
    public int Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        int result;
        if (!int.TryParse(context.SourceValue.ToString(), out result))
        {
            result = -1;
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```